# Eclipse RCP menu reutilization

Tags: eclipse, menu, rcp

While I was developing the main menu of my app I realized that there are submenues in that main menu that could be use as it in other context menu. My problem is that I dont want to write these submenues twice one for the main menu and then for the popup.

Googling a lot the only way I found was to use dynamic menus. In that case I need to write a class that implement the dynamic menu and it could be use in the main menu and in the popup menu.

Althought it work I would like to have a way to reuse menu definitions using just the plugin.xml. Is it posible?

Comment: From what I've seen, there are two ways to use the plugin.xml to implement menus: 1) using "actions" and 2) using "commands". Apparently, using "commands" is in a mature state since eclipse 3.3. So... which method are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `menus` extension point, then it is pretty easy to add the same sub-menu to the main menu and a popup menu...